# WCF Service, Download file with parameters, send data on GET request

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, wcf

jQuery has support for sending data with a `GET` request:

```
jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

Is it possible to write a WCF service that supports receiving data on a `GET` request?

An example is much appreciated.

UPDATE: Url length exceeds the limit for IE8 and IE8 is a requirement. I need to pass a lot of parameters, basically a big JSON. What I did to workaround this is to make a `POST` request,store the parameters on the server side, then set `window.location` to the service location the invoke a `GET` request that will download my file.But, I want to avoid the `POST` request and storing the file on server side because I'm in a distributed system and I have a lot of issues with this.

Comment: Check out REST WCF services or WebAPI.

Comment: I think this might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051439/how-to-call-wcf-service-using-jquery-ajax-functions

Comment: I can't use REST, nor WebAPI, cannot change the implementation right now but it's good to know for the future.

Comment: @Mutant : It is still unclear for me how to read the data on the server side

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "GET",
    UriTemplate = "SomeUrl?param1={param1}&param2={param2}"
)]
string SomeOperation(string param1, string param2);
```

And then:

```
$.get('SomeService.svc/SomeUrl?param1=SomeValue&param2=AnotherValue', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Or:

```
$.get('SomeService.svc/SomeUrl', {param1: 'SomeValue', param2: 'AnotherValue'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Is there a limit for the size of parameters? This was the root of the problem for me

Comment: If the data gets formatted within the URL, in Internet Explorer the max limit is 2083. However, in Firefox (80K+ characters) and Safari (100K+) the max length allowed is practically huge. I bet Chrome adopts the same as Firefox and/or Safari. (Source: http://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html)

Comment: I need to support this on IE8, currently is working by setting window.location to the service url. This will invoke the GET request but I need to pass a lot of parameters, basically a huge JSON. To solve this , I made a POST request with the parameters, store them on the server side and then a GET request with a short url. But, I want to avoid the POST request

Comment: POST is better for sending a huge JSON. Why do you want to avoid a POST request?

Comment: because I can't save the file received on response of a POST request

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Here link for more info - [How to: Choose between HTTP POST and HTTP GET requests for ASP.NET AJAX Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628610.aspx)

But REST services are more suitable for AJAX and calling from JS. When it is going about new service, you can use ASP.NET Web API. A lot of tutorials about it [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api)